# Kafkalistener SpringBoot failsafe

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm running spring boot with KafkaListener as my client. The question is how can we recover from a failed kafka configuration and avoid that the application stops with `Process finished with exit code 0`.
An example of an incorrect config would e.g. an incorrect endpoint url. Same scenario would apply if the Kafka server would not be reachable. So in any case the KafkaListner process should never kill the server.

```
 @Bean
open fun consumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String, String> {
    val deserializer = JsonDeserializer<Thing>()
    deserializer.addTrustedPackages("de.data.Thing")

    val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
    val serverUrl = server.substringBefore(":")
    props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = server
    props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "group"
    props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
    props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
    props[CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG] = "SASL_SSL"
    props[ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = "earliest"
    props[ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG] = false
    props[SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM] = "PLAIN"
    props[SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG] = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required " +
            "username=\"\$ConnectionString\" " +
            "password=\"Endpoint=sb://$serverUrl/;" +
            "SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=$sharedSecret\";"
    return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props,
            StringDeserializer(), StringDeserializer())

}


@Bean
open fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>? {
    val factory: ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
    factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory()
    factory.setMessageConverter(BytesJsonMessageConverter())
    return factory
}

 @KafkaListener(topics = ["topic"],
        groupId = "group",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
)
fun listenThingsChanged(@Payload thing: Thing,
                        record: ConsumerRecord<String, String>,
                        @Headers headers: MessageHeaders) {

    ....
}
```

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> at de.x.ServerAppKt.main(ServerApp.kt:11)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:825)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:631)
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:340)
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:308)
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:293)
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:267)
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:241)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:606)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:302)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:338)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:204)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:338)
> at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:312)
> at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:257)
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
> ... 19 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:737)
> ... 33 common frames omitted

Comment: What do you expect it to do? If the configuration is wrong, it is wrong - how can it possibly recover from bad configuration?

Comment: The configuration is syntactically correct. But it can not start the KafkaListener process because the url of the server is wrong or not reachable. In that case I would like that the KafkaListener process does not crash the whole server. Because my server does fulfil other tasks as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the broker is just down, the application will start fine (with versions earlier than 2.3.4 you had to set `missingTopicsFatal` to false on the container properties (it has been false by default since then).

> No resolvable bootstrap urls given in...

This is fatal - it is irrecoverable.

However, you can set `autoStartup=false` - either on the `@KafkaListener` or on the container factory.

This will prevent Spring from trying to start the containers during application initialization.

You can then start the containers yourself in a try/catch block.